# How to change the fill color of a radio button?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

My phone has black theme and i have converted the page background as white(whatever may be the theme). And now when i'm using radio button or checkbox, everything is white. even after changing the foreground color there is no change. How can i change the fill color for a radio button??

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a new style for your `CHECK BOX CONTROL TEMPLATE`, Here, copy paste the given code and change the COLOR at respective places & see if this helps. Same way you can do this for RADIO BUTTON's but you will have to change there Control template too.

```
<Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase"
   TargetType="ButtonBase">
<Setter Property="Background"
        Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush"
        Value="**SET BORDER BRUSH COLOR YOU WANT FOR YOUR CB**" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness"
        Value="3" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="2">
                    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

```
<Style x:Key="PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBase}"
       TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="**SET BACKGROUND COLOR YOU WANT FOR YOUR CB**" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="**SET BORDER BRUSH COLOR YOU WANT FOR YOUR CB**" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="3" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="simpleCheckBoxStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase}"
       TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Grid Background="Transparent"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Border x:Name="CheckBackground"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    Height="32"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Width="32" />
                            <Path x:Name="CheckMark"
                                  Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z"
                                  Fill="**SET COLOR FOR THE CHECK MARK**"
                                  FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  Height="21"
                                  IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                  Stretch="Fill"
                                  StrokeThickness="3"
                                  StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                                  Visibility="Collapsed"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Width="23" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then give your CB;

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource simpleCheckBoxStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Fill color for **CheckBackground, CheckMark and ContentContainer** in RadioButtonStyle to achieve your target. Like this,

```
<Ellipse x:Name="CheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource RedColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>
<Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Fill="{StaticResource WhiteColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{StaticResource BlackColor}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,0,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
```

And those color styles are,

```
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF0000" x:Key="RedColor"></SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFF" x:Key="WhiteColor"></SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#000000" x:Key="BlackColor"></SolidColorBrush>
```

Now keep your background as White. You're done. You can refer the following style (full code) for your reference.

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF0000" x:Key="RedColor"></SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFF" x:Key="WhiteColor"></SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="#000000" x:Key="BlackColor"></SolidColorBrush>

    <Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase" TargetType="ButtonBase">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBase}" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase}" TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="CheckBackground" Fill="{StaticResource RedColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Fill="{StaticResource WhiteColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{StaticResource BlackColor}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,0,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

You can refer the source code which i tried. It also has style for CheckBox which might help you.
http://1drv.ms/1sS4loX